# How to find all tags with a specific data- attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I need to find all tags that have an 'error' data bound to them using jQuery.
This is what I have done. It's not working because I added the data attribute with code.

```
$('form input').data('error',1);

console.log( $('form input[data-error]') ); // This is empty
```

How can I retrieve all of them?

Comment: What is the attribute actually called? `valid-error`, `data-error` or `data-valid-error`?

Comment: Yes, I modified it.

Comment: data jQuery method don't create data attribute it keep that value internally somehow.

Comment: It’s still unclear what the exact attribute name is. Is it `data-error` and nothing with `valid`?

Comment: valid-error was a mistake. I corrected that. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter()`

```
$('form input').filter(function(){
     return $(this).data('error'); // adjust if boolean not sufficient    
}).doSomething();
```

Comment: Accepted. In fact I had to wait for 5 minutes to do it :-)

Comment: Important to recognize that element property setters don't actually update attributes in almost all cases

Comment: I just need to know if this list is empty or not. is there any simpler answer to this?

Comment: Just check length of the collection it produces... `var hasErrors = $('form input').filter(func........   }).length`

Answer (score 2):

You can use native JavaScript (no jQuery is needed), simply use:

[Document.querySelectorAll()](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) with a [Selectors Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) (similar to CSS)

```js
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('[data-animal-type="fish"]');
console.log(elms.length);
```

```html
<li data-animal-type="bird">Owl</li>
<li data-animal-type="fish">Salmon</li>
<li data-animal-type="spider">Tarantula</li>
```

Selector are very powerful and allow more advanced selection like:

> E[foo^="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly
>   with the string "bar"  E[foo$="bar"]  an E element whose "foo"
>   attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar"     E[foo*="bar"]  an E
>   element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar"
>   E[foo|="en"]  an E element whose "foo" attribute has a hyphen-separated
>   list of values beginning (from the left) with "en"